# jQuery image zoom with details on hover

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, hover, zooming

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that can zoom a thumbnail and also display some details about the image. More or less the same as on google image search.

I've found http://www.malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/ and that's what I'm looking for except that this one can't display additional information.

Anyone know if there is a plugin that's able to do what I'm looking for..?

Comment: Actually, very simple and easy to update script. Recommended to everyone who can write a code in JQuery. 
I've updated this script for variable width/height of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a link that has 15 plugins I've used two of them with good success. http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but none of them is really what I'm looking for. I'm hoping to find something that's more like the one Google is using on the image search.

Comment: I did something similar for a CMS I did using

Comment: I did something similar for a CMS I did using a hidden div that would store the other info and on hover would expand, like `<div id'main' class='zoom'><div id='hidden'><!-- content --></div><img ></div>` then in the script add `$('.zoom').hover()` and show the bigger image and other html. I used this method on a realestate site to show details of listing, kinda like what I think you are trying to do. Hope this points you in the right way.

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah, I guess I'm going to do something similar because I can't find any existing plugin that's doing exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Although I found http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/popout-details-on-hover-w-css/ which is more or less what I'm looking for.

Comment: I ended up writing this on my own, at the moment my code is a bit messy. But as soon I have it ready I'll post an example here. Thanks again Vaughn for trying to help.