# OnMouseOver effect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a Cool OnMouseOver effect incorporating JavaScript in my HTML file. I have a picture with a map. I have about 7 different areas inside that map. I would like to add an OnMouseOver effect to each of those areas so that they can zoom in smoothly. Somebody knows how may I achieve this? Thank you very much!!

-Diego.

Comment: Possible Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792248/jquery-image-zoom-with-details-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is split that map into 7 images, when one of those images is clicked you then zoom it - a library such as jQuery can help with this.

You can find instructions on animating image size with jQuery [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/animate-the-size-of-an-image).